# Powershell 3.0: After I save a working script, if I close and then reopen the script I receive an error message when I try to run it

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I just wrote this code:

```
Get-ChildItem 'R:\Source\Path' |
 Where-Object { $_.Name -notlike '*_*' } |
 Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name > 'C:\Destination\Path\Test.txt' |
 Clear-Host
 Invoke-Item 'C:\Destination\Path\Test.txt'
```

which worked perfectly. I saved the code and then closed power shell. When I reopened powershell and ran this specific program, it produced the following error message:

> File C:\Users\Galen\Powershell Code\InvokeItem.ps1 cannot be loaded
>   because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more
>   information, see about_Execution_Policies at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
>       + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

I am the administrator on this computer. What happened?

Comment: What do you see when you run Get-ExecutionPolicy? Did you read the help file that is explicitly mentioned right there in the error?

Comment: I did, and as a very new powershell user, it didn't make much sense. If I copy that exact code and paste it into a new code environment, it runs perfectly fine.

Comment: Running G-EP returned undefined.

Comment: [First, try reading the error message](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/06/25/9802453.aspx). As EBGreen points out, you need to read the documentation.

Comment: Yes, sorry Bill, I did read the error message. I didn't mean to imply that I didn't. I read the error message but as I stated before it didn't make much sense to me. Evidently I am a restricted user, and despite having admin status, I cannot change my execution policy. Ignoring that point, according to the documentation, a restricted user can't run .ps1 scripts. But i CAN run .ps1 scripts, except after I have saved them. What is so different about a script before and after saving it?

Comment: How exactly are you running them without saving them first?

Comment: That's more or less what I've been struggling to understand! I write the code, and run it, which automatically saves it. I then go to save-as, and save it under my user folder, in a folder called 'power shell code'. If I close Powershell, and reopen the code under it's new save name, it produces the error message I posted above. But! If I then copy and paste the code into a new window and run it, it works fine.

Comment: You keep saying powershell, but I suspect that you mean Powershell ISE?

Comment: Yes -- you are correct. I'm sorry for using the terms so loosely.

Comment: The ISE runs in a very different environment than a regular powershell console. I suspect that when you run it the first time it is running completely in memory and when you run it the second time it is running in a prompt environment hosted in the ISE.

Answer (score 1):

What is your ExecutionPolicy set to ?

```
PS C:\Users\Me\Desktop> ExecutionPolicy
```

If it's **Restricted** , then it runs PowerShell in Interactive mode only which is why it ran before.

If you are an admin, then try setting it to Unrestricted and execute your script

```
PS C:\Users\Me\Desktop> Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

More Info -  [Using the Set-ExecutionPolicy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176961.aspx)

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by interactive mode? In the literature it says restricted users cannot run Windows Powershell profiles (.ps1). But isn't my script file a .ps1 anyway? What's so different about it after I save it?

Comment: It means you can only execute commands when in a powershell console but if you save it in a .ps1, and try to run it, it will not run. That is the Restricted Policy. Did you try changing it to Unrestricted ?

Comment: I did try to change it -- I am an administrator on the computer (I confirmed this via checking administrator groups), but when I try to change my policy to unrestricted I get an error message. Specifically: Access to the registry key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell' is denied.

Comment: I have not encountered that before but I found these steps on a microsoft [Forum](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/access-to-the-registry-key-for-powershel-is-denied/9e5cb142-ee69-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5?auth=1)             * Run: regedt32
* Goto HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell
* Right-Click > Permissions 
* Select, and add your account, grant it "Full Control" privileges

Comment: Hmm...strange. I went in and edited the permissions as you indicated and still no luck with changing permissions. I even restarted the computer just to be sure the changes took effect.